Unable to GET in K8s WSL2
I have two Kubernetes pods, running under Docker Desktop in WSL2 (local dev test PC).
One pod contains a web app and the other a REST API.
I can successfully login a user in the browser, and the REST API’s logs show that the POST request at http://restapi-service:8080/User was accepted.
However, when I then try to send a GET request to http://restapi-service:8080/Job/jobs?userId=3, I’m getting a  “net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED” error.
I have verified that the same GET request is working fine when not running in Kubernetes.
It seems to be also working when testing with wget from the web app pod:
$ wget http://restapi-service:8080/Job/jobs?userId=3
Connecting to restapi-service:8080 (10.100.127.206:8080)
saving to 'jobs?userId=3'
jobs?userId=3        100% |******************************************************************************************************************************************|  1809  0:00:00 ETA
'jobs?userId=3' saved

I also tried with the fully qualified domain name restapi-service.default.svc.cluster.local but it made no difference.
Services descriptions:
$ kubectl describe service webui
Name:                     webui-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=webui
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.104.148.120
IPs:                      10.104.148.120
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               5173/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32000/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.0.95:5173
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Internal Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

$ kubectl describe service restapi
Name:                     restapi-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=restapi
Type:                     ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.100.127.206
IPs:                      10.100.127.206
Port:                     8080  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.0.92:8080
Port:                     8081  8081/TCP
TargetPort:               8081/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.0.92:8081
Session Affinity:         None
Internal Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The browser app runs in your browser, and it can't see the Kubernetes-internal Service names.  This is fundamentally the same problem as "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend but in Kubernetes; I'd use Ingress (or Gateway) resources instead of manually setting up the reverse proxy I describe there.

@DavidMaze, Since everything is on a single machine, I've tried to apply the workaround you've suggested, although I'm not sure I did it right. The API's service yaml has port and targetPort set to 8080, so I modified the fetch call to localhost:8080, but now I can't even login.

If both components have Ingress resources set up, and they're served from different paths on the same host name, then your fetch() call should just use the URL path like /api/whatever, no host or port.

@DavidMaze I haven't setup ingress/gateway as this is a local dev machine and I want to focus on development. Is there no other way around it when using kubernetes?

Kubernetes is normally a remote, clustered environment.  You could set up your own reverse proxy to simulate the setup, but I wouldn't try to use Kubernetes as part of your day-to-day work flow.

@DavidMaze, yes, I'm aware of that but I'm trying to stay focused on development without diving into devops too much right now. However, it seems that I have no choice but to learn about implementing ingress. Thanks.

I managed to solve this myself. In case anyone else is having the same issue with Docker Desktop/WSL2/Kubernetes, here is what worked for me:
Web app service YAML:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: webapp
  ports:
    - name: web
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5173
      nodePort: 30080

Rest API service YAML:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
    - name: restapi
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30081

Get the WSL IP by running:
ip addr show eth0 | grep inet

Then use that IP with the node port of the API in the fetch command, E.g.:
fetch(http://172.23.233.198:30081/Job/jobs?userId=3)


Your solution does not match the question. In your question you are asking why get request is workimg and post doesn't. Also you are using service name as host.

@MirceaSirghi, the above steps got the GET request finally working. The key here was to get the IP of the WSL virtual machine and use that in the fetch commands. Please note that this solution is specifically for the case of running K8s under WSL2, as stated in the OP.

The solution you posted is one of the best I have seen so far on this issue. The problem is that, as stated in the question, your post request was working, whilst get was not. So there may have been some changes you have made in between and you came up to this solution. But your initial state seems to be lost, and that was the most interesting to solve. Still, what you have posted here is the something I was also looking before as I am also using WSL2. However, I plan to use Ingress instead.

The simplest hack to get your local dev setup working is to force your OS to resolve the container names back to localhost.
sounds like you're on windows. temporarily edit c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
with
127.0.0.1  restapi-service
127.0.0.1  webui-service

you could even shim / extend a slightly more useful setup using something like dnsmasq to catch a hostname glob pattern.
The other comments present a myriad of options suited to non local dev environments.

Thanks but I tried that and it doesn't solve the problem.

Your post request is simple:
http://restapi-service:8080/User

However your get request has additional things in it:
http://restapi-service:8080/Job/jobs?userId=3

So, if you configured ingress to run for http://restapi-service:8080/User you should also configure it to run for http://restapi-service:8080/Job.
A better way would be to have the same request pattern:
http://restapi-service:8080/<your app name here>/.*

In case you specify /.* allow regex by adding:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"

